# connection between kafka and elasticsearch using python

Tags: python, elasticsearch, apache-kafka

I'm new about using Kafka and elasticsearch. I've been trying to use Elastic search but I've some problem. I've grow up a docker compose file with all the images needed for building the environment then using kafka I've product into a specific topic the data and then I need to take from Kafka 's consumer data into a pub/sub system for sending data for the ingestion into elasticsearch.
I implement all this using python. I've seen that into the port and localhost as ip elasticsearch appear instead for kibana in the page appear the following sentence:
kibana server is not ready yet

the consumer python is something similar to it from which I take data from a topic:

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
# Import sys module
import sys

# Import json module to serialize data
import json

# Initialize consumer variable and set property for JSON decode
consumer = KafkaConsumer ('JSONtopic',bootstrap_servers = ['localhost:9092'],
value_deserializer=lambda m: json.loads(m.decode('utf-8')))
for message in consumer:
 print("Consumer records:\n")
 print(message)
 print("\nReading from JSON data\n")
 print("Name:",message[6]['name'])
 print("Email:",message[6]['email'])
 # Terminate the script
 sys.exit()
```

The goal is to use elasticsearch for doing analysis so I need to use it as backend as for visualize data into kibana. It could be really appreciate also a tutorial to follow for understanding what I should do for link this informations.
(P.s. data follow without problem from a topic to another one but the problem is to take this information and insert into elastic and have the possibility to visualize these informations)

Answer (score 0):

If you're pushing data from Kafka to Elasticsearch then doing it with the Consumer API is typically not a good idea, since there are tools that exist that do it much better and handle more functionality.

For example:

- Kafka Connect (e.g.  https://rmoff.dev/kafka-elasticsearch-video)
- Logstash

Comment: I had seen your video thanks for the answer, I manage to solve my problem using a different approach, maybe not the best in terms of performance [link](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html) . Thanks in advance